# MySQL tables relation in Qt Model/View Programming

Tags: mysql, qt

I store data in a table **MyTable** in MySQL, and use Qt QSqlQueryModel to display it in a tableView. So now I have a dialog displaying the table information. For example, **MyTable** is:

> id  name
>
> 01   Bird
>
> 02   Cat
>
> 03   Dog
>
> 04   Fish

Now i want to add a category table by adding a new listView in Qt GUI. For example, the table **MyLocation** can be:

> id location
>
> 01   All locations
>
> 02   On land
>
> 03   Else

I want to manipulate both tables with Qt Model/View style. How can I connect two tables, so when I click

> All locations

in listView, in tableView all items in MyTable are shown? When I click

> On land

in listView, in tableView only

> 02 Cat
>
> 03 Dog

are shown?

I know QSqlRelationalTableModel can display two tables with friend relationship, but in my case, how can I create a model based on father child relationship? While the listView in Qt GUI shows the category, the tableView shows the items inside that group?

I'm thinking about create some tables to store the elements in different groups, since one item can be in group 1 and 2 at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

The two models (QSqlTableModel should be fine), one for locations and one for animals don't need to be explicitly connected each other in some way in Qt, whilst they do on the SQL side.
For animals, schema should be:

```
(id, name, location_id)
```

where location_id is a foreign key on the table MyLocation. 
When current location changes on the QListView, carry out current location id and activate a slot which alters the WHERE clause in the animal model.

```
void doFilter(int location)
{
    animals_model.setFilter(QString("location_id=%1").arg(location_id));
    animals_model.select();
}
```

when user selects "all locations", activate another slot to clear filters:

```
void resetFilter()
{
    animals_model.setFilter("");
    animals_model.select();
}
```

In short: first model let user choose something which acts as a filter for a query on the second one.

Comment: Thank you for showing me the function of setFilter. However, one element in animals can belong to several locations, so for example, fish can be in location "sea", "river", and "all locations". But location_id will only indicate one place where fish can be divided into. I'm thinking of making a bunch of tables to group different locations, such as, table sea will have all the id's of animals living in sea, table river will have all the id's of animals in river, so one element in animals table can belong to both sea and river. I'm wondering how to do this in QSqlQueryModel. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a better design of your tables.
There are two ways to do this. Here's the simple one first, but I don't recommend it for professional use.

**Method One - Flag the records**

Animals table would look like this:
{animal_id, name, is_land, is_river, is_lake, is_air, is_ocean, is_mountain, is_valey, is_north_pole, is_africa,.......etc.)

This is pretty stupid but it gets the job done.

**Method two - intersections matrix**

I am not sure if *intersections matrix* makes any sense in English but in Computer Science in U of Prishtina, Kosovo during the 90's it was called in Albanian "Matrica e kryqëzimeve"

You should have 3 tables.

1. Animals (animal_id, name)
2. Locations (loc_id, name)
3. ani_loc_matrix( animal_id, loc_id)

It is harder program with this method because SQL is not made this way, but it has an incredible speed when querying the database.

The idea here is simple. If an animal belongs to a location you just add a record in the matrix table with animal_id and loc_id. You can add multiple locations for the same animal for example

```
INSERT INTO ani_loc_matrix VALUES (01, 01)
```

where the first 01 would be the id of a fish and the second 01 would be the id of Ocean.

if your locations table had something like this:

- 01 Ocean
- 02 Sea
- 03 Lake
- 04 River
- 06 Pond
- 07 North Pole

... you could add the following

```
INSERT INTO ani_loc_matrix VALUES (01, 01) 
INSERT INTO ani_loc_matrix VALUES (01, 02) 
INSERT INTO ani_loc_matrix VALUES (01, 03) 
INSERT INTO ani_loc_matrix VALUES (01, 04) 
INSERT INTO ani_loc_matrix VALUES (01, 05)
```

To check if there is fish in the north pole type this:

```
SELECT * FROM ani_loc_matrix WHERE animal_id=01 AND loc_id=07
```

To find all fish locations

```
SELECT * FROM ani_loc_matrix WHERE animal_id=01
```

To find what lives in all waters

```
SELECT * FROM ani_loc_matrix WHERE loc_id=01 OR loc_id=02 OR loc_id=03 OR loc_id=04 OR loc_id=05 OR loc_id=06
```

To get the actual animal names you have to join tables:
    SELECT * FROM animals as a, ani_loc_matrix as m WHERE a.animal_id=m.animal_id AND m.animal_id=01

Enjoy.

(FLOSSK Member)